# OpenAPI add extra examples without having to redefine the default example

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

In OpenAPI 3, I have a reponses block which refers to an existing Model.

```
responses:
    200:
      description: successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyModel'
```

Because MyModel includes `example` fields, I get a nice example response in the UI. Lovely.

I'd like to add some additional examples to this endpoint.
I can create an `examples` field (Underneath `application/json` ) and show multiple examples with a nice UI drop-down.
However if I do this I loose the default example, and have to re-define the default example for my users to see.
e.g. I can only define a brand new set of examples, rather than adding a new one.

*Is there a way when defining an examples block to include the default example directly?*
eg I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
examples:
    default:
       $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyModel'
    myOtherExample:
       value: {"A": "B"}
```

It compiles OK but shows an empty example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way when defining an examples block to include the default example directly?

This is not supported. If a custom `example` or `examples` are provided in an OpenAPI definition, Swagger UI uses these custom examples instead of auto-generated examples.

Users can still see the default values in the schema documentation on the Model/Schema tab in Swagger  UI.